# Does the tenor voice have a falsetto that begins at D4?

Tags: voice

I, a tenor, remember learning to sing a certain hymn years ago. It went up to D. It felt high way back then. Nowadays it is not high at all. I would probably transpose it so that the highest note would be F#4.

Something happens at D4. I go into some kind of falsetto voice. I do think the real falsetto begins at eg Ab4 or Ab4. My teacher told me this but had no good answer about what is going on.
Does the tenor voice have a falsetto that begins at D4?

Comment: I don't think we can be that precise - vocal ranges are never that standardised - and break points will vary considerably.

Comment: You mean that it is more like a "passage" rather than something that happens at a certain note? This falsetto is just what some refer to as the primo passagio?

Comment: There's an overlap for some, others switch within a note or two.

Comment: Ok I see. People often talk about it as a certain but it is not how it works for me

Comment: There is a lot of confusion and misleading information regarding vocal ranges and sound production, a lot was developed for pedagogical purposes but it not scientifcally accurate about the physiology of singing. For example, the idea of "passagi" is a principle we can all experience: singing lower feels different to singing in the middle of our range, and singing at the upper end again feels different. This is perhaps a useful distinction for teaching purposes. But you do not use a different physical method of sound production in each range. Falsetto *is* a different physical method of sound

Comment: production – but it doesn't have a direct relationship with a pitch range. You can sing falsetto at a range of pitches, which will most often overlap with pitches you are capable of producing using your normal siging voice (called the "modal" voice). So the idea that falsetto "starts" at a certain pitch doesn't have a clear meaning. Now, if you think you should be able to sing D4 in your modal voice, but you always end up slipping into falsetto, you need to strengthen or get more familiar with using your normal voice, using all the proper techniques of good sound production, at that pitch

Comment: the problem is: teachers talk about falsetto without defining it. Sometimes I wonder if they use head voice and falsetto as synonyms.

Comment: @JudyN your two comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your question makes about as much sense as "does a race car have a third gear that begins at 75km/h"?  There is no fixed minimum pitch for falsetto for tenors in general, and not even for any certain tenor in particular.

I have a range of about an octave where I can choose to switch to falsetto or not (or transition into it smoothly over a somewhat smaller range), and a large part of a singer's development is extending the reach of their registers and blending and matching their characters so that you don't have the sound quality hacked into disjoint pieces in the middle of phrases but can choose and/or mask your breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that YOUR voice may have a falsetto that starts at D.  But which D are we talking about, and are you sure you're a tenor?   D just above middle C is top-of-the-range for a bass or maybe a baritone, but routine for a tenor.  The next D up is remarkable for a tenor, and the F♯ above most unlikely in full voice!

So, I guess we're talking about the lower one.  Perhaps your voice has a tenor quality but you're just beginning to find its range.

Comment: It says D4 in the question

Comment: I can easily sing up to F#4.